# passing loop of components to html in react

Tags: reactjs

```
formRowData() 
{
    if (!this.props.payments.result) 
    {
        return;
    }
    const tableRows = this.props.payments.result.content.map((payment) => {
        payment = payment.payment;
        return <TransactionTableRow key={payment.paymentId} transactionRowData={payment}/>
    })

    return tableRows;
}
```

This is my loop for multiple tr components which I am trying to display on the page as follows

```
<TransactionsDashboard merchant={this.props.merchant} transactionsData={this.formRowData()} statsTableData={this.getStatsTableData()} />
```

**My transaction Row component:**

```
import React from 'react'

const TransactionTableRow = ({key,transactionRowData}) => {
    return (
      <tr key={key}>
            <td height="70"><span className="txt-spcng">19 Jan 17<br /><small className="grey-txt">19 Jan 17</small></span></td>
            <td>{transactionRowData.paymentId}</td>
            <td>KTU7-ZAUOSPZ</td>
            <td><span className="txt-limit">firstname.lastnasdsd</span></td>
            <td className="amnt-dbt">&#8377; {transactionRowData.amount}</td>
            <td><span className="txt-limit">Payment Successdd sdsd d</span></td>
            <td align="center"><div className="tl-tip"><a href="javscript:void(0)" className="icon-dotted"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
    )
}

export default TransactionTableRow
```

**But i get an error Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the keys aren't unique?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth They are unique have checked.

Comment: It seems that React disagrees with you ;)  Can you do `console.log(payment.paymentId)` *inside* the `map` body, and add the result to your question?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Added

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am displaying {transactionRows} as follows on my comtainer is that correct.

Comment: Could you `console.log(key)` inside `return()` of TransactionTableRow and show me the result?

Comment: @bharadhwaj Its coming as undefined :/

Comment: ^ exactly the problem! Change that to something which is defined and unique as well, should solve your problem. :)

Comment: But data of key is being passed ..

Comment: But that is showing as `undefined`, right?

Comment: @bharadhwaj - but that's the only child element, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is simple one, `key` is a reserved keyword, it will not get passed to child component, use some other name, use this:

```
<TransactionTableRow unique_id={payment.paymentId}....



const TransactionTableRow = ({unique_id,transactionRowData}) => {
    return (
      <tr key={unique_id}>
       .....
```

If you want to verify this just put a `console.log('key', key)`, like this:

```
const TransactionTableRow = ({unique_id,transactionRowData}) => {
     console.log('key', key);
     return (
     ....
```

It will print `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for you to assing key to the table row in the `TransactionTableRow` component since you are already assigning to it inside the map. Also since `key` is a reserved attribute it is not passed down as a prop. Change you code to the following

```
formRowData() 
{
    if (!this.props.payments.result) 
    {
        return;
    }
    const tableRows = this.props.payments.result.content.map((payment) => {
        payment = payment.payment;
        return <TransactionTableRow key={payment.paymentId} transactionRowData={payment}/>
    })

    return tableRows;
}
```

TransactionRow component

```
const TransactionTableRow = ({transactionRowData}) => {
    return (
      <tr>
            <td height="70"><span className="txt-spcng">19 Jan 17<br /><small className="grey-txt">19 Jan 17</small></span></td>
            <td>{transactionRowData.paymentId}</td>
            <td>KTU7-ZAUOSPZ</td>
            <td><span className="txt-limit">firstname.lastnasdsd</span></td>
            <td className="amnt-dbt">&#8377; {transactionRowData.amount}</td>
            <td><span className="txt-limit">Payment Successdd sdsd d</span></td>
            <td align="center"><div className="tl-tip"><a href="javscript:void(0)" className="icon-dotted"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
    )
}

export default TransactionTableRow
```

Answer (score -1):

It is considered duplicate because you assign the same key to TransactionTableRow and then the tr element within it. You can remove the key in tr element. Please refer to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  React is (or should) only be considering keys of siblings.

Comment: The key should be only in TransationTableRow, it;s not needed in tr element within - more explicit explanantion on reactjs documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: Sure, it's unnecessary - but it won't break anything.